# kernel fisher discriminant

Tags: machine-learning, classification, kernel

I have been using LDA to try to build a disease prognosis using medical data for a group of patients and a group of controls, and after limited success I decided to try to use kernel Fisher discriminant analysis. I wrote code in Matlab based on the paper by Mika.

This method seems to be very very sensitive. For example using say 80 rows of data this method is amazingly good at seperating the data into the 2 classes accurately (no overlap at all), but removing the first row of the data and then using this method leads to a terrible discrimination between classes.

Any ideas on why this might be occurring would be greatly appreciated.
I have 24 measurements from each patient and the kernel map I have been using is a polynomial map, with $$k(x,x')=(x \cdot x')^2.$$ This corresponds to mapping $\mathbb{R}^{24}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{576}$, sending $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots, x_{24})$ to $(x_1^2,x_1x_2,\dots,x_1x_{24},x_2x_1,x_2^2,\dots, x_{24}^2)$